# split the string and convert to array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, split

I have a string data, I need to convert to array of objects in javascript

Below the code tried

```
var splitarr = sample.split('|');
var result = splitarr.map(e=>{
  details: e,
  values: splitarr[e]
})
```

```
var sample =  "finance=60|IT=88|sales=50"


Expected Output

[
  {"details": "finance","tag":60},
  {"details": "IT","tag":88},
  {"details": "sales","tag":50}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another split by `=`, try:

```js
var sample =  "finance=60|IT=88|sales=50";
var splitarr = sample.split('|');

var result = splitarr.map(e=>{
  let keyVal = e.split('=');
  return { details: keyVal[0], tag:keyVal[1] }
})

console.log(result);
```

Also when you return object from arrow function you neeed to use brackets `()`, otherwise it will be considered as block of code, try:

```js
var sample =  "finance=60|IT=88|sales=50";
var splitarr = sample.split('|');

var result1 = splitarr.map(e=>{
  details: e
})

console.log(result1);

var result2 = splitarr.map(e=>({
  details: e
}))

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of transforming string to object.

```js
const sample =  "finance=60|IT=88|sales=50";

const result = sample
  .split('|')
  .map((e) => e.split('='))
  .map(([details, tag]) => ({ details, tag }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` to extract all pairs eg. `"finance=60"` by using `string.match(regex)` which will return array of pairs and then use `Array.map()` to map into array of objects.

```js
const text =  "finance=60|IT=88|sales=50";
const convertToObject = (str) => {
  const list = str.match(/\w+=\d+/g);
  return list.map(ele => {
    const [details, tag] = ele.split("=");
    return { details, tag };
  });
}
console.log(convertToObject(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observations :**

- Instead of `values` property it should be `tag`.
- As splitter will be a simple `array` of elements. This `splitarr[e]` will not work or not exist.

You can use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to get the `details` and `tag` value.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const sample =  "finance=60|IT=88|sales=50";

const splitarr = sample.split('|');

const result = splitarr.map((e) => {
    return {
    details: e.split('=')[0],
    tag: e.split('=')[1]
  }
});

console.log(result);
```